# Semicolon is optional in JavaScript. However, could I omit the semicolons in the for loop?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Semicolon is optional in JavaScript. However, could I omit the semicolons in the for loop? For example:

```
for (let i = 0 i < arr.length i++) {
    console.log(arr[i])
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript, I'm coming from C and C++ where semicolon is a must.

Comment: No. Trying it out would have quickly answered this

Comment: Semicolons *as statement terminators before a line break* are optional in *most* situations (not all). The `;` inside a `for` isn't a statement terminator. It's part of the syntax of the `for`, and a line break there won't do its job for it.

Answer (score -2):

Semicolons are used when you have more than one statements.
If you have only one statement in for loop , you don't need to put semicolon.